# preg_match_all exclude .gif extension

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, preg-match-all

I'm working on a website where i have setup to get the first and the second image from wordpress posts to use as custom homepage layout.

I'm using this code:

```
//GET FIRST IMAGE ON POST
function get_first_image($size = false) {

    global $post, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    $first_img = '';

    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];

    if (empty($first_img)) {
        return;
    }

    if ($size && $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['crop'] == 1) {
        $size = '-' . $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['width'] . 'x' . $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$size]['height'] . '.jpg';
        $pattern = '/-\d+x\d+\.jpg$/i';
        $first_img = preg_replace($pattern, $size, $first_img);
    }

    return $first_img;

}
```

My problem is that my client use JPG for pictures in her blog, but there's some .GIF images in article, these .GIF i want to jump through and get only if the image is a valid .JPG image, how can i do this?

Comment: Use proper HTML parsing techniques (such as `DOMDocument`) to get all of your `<img>` tags, don't try and use regular expressions. You can then use `pathinfo` on the `src` attribute to check the extension.

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks for your reply, i found one code with DOMDocument to use instead of preg_match_all, but now the problem it's when a image is inside an HREF that have the image path, in this case i think that the code is confusing with the path on HREF and SRC.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will include jp(e)g and png, so will not include gif.

```
<img\s.*src='?".+(jpe?g|png).+>
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei David, i've tried to use your code, but the output was only the "jpg", not the entire URL, maybe i did something wrong?